# Masked Numpy arrays much slower than normal numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, nan

I have a function that calculates pairwise correlation between all pairs of rows in a numpy array. It was working fine, but then I remembered that every so often I am going to have to deal with missing data. I used the masked array to try and solve this but it slows down the computation by quite a bit. Any ideas around using the masked functions. The real bottleneck I think is going to be in the `np.ma.dot` function. but I have added some profiling I quickly mocked up with iPython. I should say the 5000 is on the lower end of the spectrum in terms of number of rows these arrays are going to have. Some might have upwards of 300,000. The code with the masked arrays looks about 20 times slower than the code without, but obviously with missing data, the code without the masked arrays just produces an NaN every so often.

First a quick and dirty way to generating some sample data

```
genotypes = np.empty((5000,200))
for i in xrange(5000):
    genotypes[i] = np.random.binomial(3,.333, size=200)

pValues = np.random.uniform(0,1,5000)
```

Then the functions to test

```
 def testMask(pValsArray, genotypeArray):
    nSNPs = len(pValsArray)-1
    genotypeArray = np.ma.masked_array(genotypeArray, np.isnan(genotypeArray))
    chisq = np.sum(-2 * np.log(pValsArray))
    ms = genotypeArray.mean(axis=1)[(slice(None,None,None),None)]
    datam = genotypeArray - ms
    datass = np.ma.sqrt(np.ma.sum(datam**2, axis=1))
    runningSum = 0
    for i in xrange(nSNPs):
        temp = np.ma.dot(datam[i:],datam[i].T)
        d = (datass[i:]*datass[i])
        rs = temp / d
        rs = np.absolute(rs)[1:]
        runningSum += 3.25 * np.sum(rs) +  .75 * np.dot(rs, rs)
    sigmaSq = 4*nSNPs+2*runningSum
    E = 2*nSNPs
    df = (2*(E*E))/sigmaSq
    runningSum = sigmaSq/(2*E)
    d = chisq/runningSum
    brownsP = stats.chi2.sf(d, df)
    return brownsP

def testNotMask(pValsArray, genotypeArray):
    nSNPs = len(pValsArray)-1
    chisq = np.sum(-2 * np.log(pValsArray))
    ms = genotypeArray.mean(axis=1)[(slice(None,None,None),None)]
    datam = genotypeArray - ms
    datass = np.sqrt(stats.ss(datam, axis=1))
    runningSum = 0
    for i in xrange(nSNPs):
        temp = np.dot(datam[i:],datam[i].T)
        d = (datass[i:]*datass[i])
        rs = temp / d
        rs = np.absolute(rs)[1:]
        runningSum += 3.25 * np.sum(rs) +  .75 * np.dot(rs, rs)
    sigmaSq = 4*nSNPs+2*runningSum
    E = 2*nSNPs
    df = (2*(E*E))/sigmaSq
    runningSum = sigmaSq/(2*E)
    d = chisq/runningSum
    brownsP = stats.chi2.sf(d, df)
    return brownsP
```

And some timing

```
%timeit testMask(pValues, genotypes)
1 loops, best of 3: 14.3 s per loop

%timeit testNotMask(pValues, genotypes)
1 loops, best of 3: 678 ms per loop
```

add some missing data and go again:

```
randis = np.random.randint(0,5000, 10)
randjs = np.random.randint(0,200, 10)

for i,j in zip(randis, randjs):
    genotypes[i,j] = None



%timeit testMask(pValues, genotypes)
1 loops, best of 3: 14.2 s per loop

%timeit testNotMask(pValues, genotypes)
1 loops, best of 3: 654 ms per loop
```

and some profiling:

```
%prun

       2559677 function calls in 15.045 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     9791    5.259    0.001    5.259    0.001 {method 'copy' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
     4999    2.877    0.001   11.888    0.002 extras.py:949(dot)
     9794    1.566    0.000    1.566    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.copyto}
    14997    1.497    0.000    1.564    0.000 {numpy.core._dotblas.dot}
    30007    0.559    0.000    0.559    0.000 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
    94996    0.450    0.000    0.875    0.000 core.py:2751(_update_from)
   864970    0.347    0.000    0.347    0.000 {getattr}
     5000    0.346    0.000    0.802    0.000 core.py:1065(__call__)
        1    0.240    0.240   15.045   15.045 <ipython-input-115-2aab1c8ea4c5>:1(testMask)
     5000    0.196    0.000    0.196    0.000 core.py:771(__call__)
     5001    0.147    0.000    0.551    0.000 core.py:917(__call__)
    24996    0.143    0.000    0.609    0.000 core.py:2930(__getitem__)
    54998    0.140    0.000    0.775    0.000 core.py:2776(__array_finalize__)
   419985    0.126    0.000    0.126    0.000 {method 'update' of 'dict' objects}
        1    0.093    0.093    0.111    0.111 core.py:5990(power)
   339994    0.077    0.000    0.077    0.000 {isinstance}
    50015    0.072    0.000    0.072    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.array}
    60002    0.060    0.000    0.568    0.000 {method 'view' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
     5000    0.060    0.000    0.199    0.000 core.py:2626(__new__)
    14999    0.058    0.000    7.412    0.000 core.py:3341(filled)
    25005    0.055    0.000    0.092    0.000 core.py:609(getdata)
```

**EDIT:**

I tried perimosocordiae's answers but I am still getting `nan`s. It looks like the `mean`, `stats.ss` and `np.sqrt` function all care about `nan` values.

```
def fastNotMask(pValsArray, genotypeArray):
    nSNPs = len(pValsArray)-1
    chisq = np.sum(-2 * np.log(pValsArray))
    ms = genotypeArray.mean(axis=1)[(slice(None,None,None),None)]
    print ms
    datam = genotypeArray - ms
    print datam
    datass = np.sqrt(stats.ss(datam, axis=1))
    print datass
    runningSum = 0
    for i in xrange(nSNPs):
        temp = np.dot(datam[i:],datam[i].T)
        d = (datass[i:]*datass[i])
        rs = temp / d
        rs = np.absolute(rs)[1:]
        runningSum += 3.25 * np.nansum(rs) +  .75 * np.nansum(rs * rs)
    print runningSum
    sigmaSq = 4*nSNPs+2*runningSum
    E = 2*nSNPs
    df = (2*(E*E))/sigmaSq
    runningSum = sigmaSq/(2*E)
    d = chisq/runningSum
    brownsP = stats.chi2.sf(d, df)
    return brownsP
```

Testing this with a small amount of output shows that the `nan`s aren't being properly handled.

```
pValues = np.random.uniform(0,1,10)

genotypes = np.empty((10,10))
for i in xrange(10):
    genotypes[i] = np.random.binomial(2,.5, size=10)

randis = np.random.randint(0,10, 2)
randjs = np.random.randint(0,10, 2)

for i,j in zip(randis, randjs):
    genotypes[i,j] = None

print testfastMask(pValues, genotypes)



[[ 1.5]
 [ 1.2]
 [ 0.9]
 [ 1.2]
 [ 1.1]
 [ 0.6]
 [ nan]
 [ 1.1]
 [ nan]
 [ 0.8]]
[[-0.5 -0.5  0.5  0.5 -0.5 -0.5  0.5  0.5 -0.5  0.5]
 [-0.2  0.8 -0.2 -0.2 -0.2 -0.2 -0.2  0.8 -0.2 -0.2]
 [-0.9  0.1 -0.9  1.1  0.1 -0.9  1.1  0.1  0.1  0.1]
 [-0.2 -0.2 -0.2 -0.2  0.8 -0.2 -0.2 -1.2  0.8  0.8]
 [-0.1 -0.1 -0.1 -0.1 -0.1 -0.1  0.9 -0.1  0.9 -1.1]
 [-0.6  1.4  0.4 -0.6 -0.6  0.4 -0.6 -0.6  0.4  0.4]
 [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
 [-0.1  0.9 -1.1 -1.1  0.9 -0.1  0.9 -1.1  0.9 -0.1]
 [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
 [ 1.2 -0.8 -0.8  0.2 -0.8  0.2  1.2  0.2  0.2 -0.8]]
[ 1.58113883  1.26491106  2.21359436  1.8973666   1.70293864  2.0976177
         nan  2.62678511         nan  2.36643191]
nan
nan
```

Did I miss something here? Could this be a version issue. I am using python 2.7 and numpy 1.7.1?

Cheers for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: The original answer doesn't work for numpy versions <= 1.8, in which `np.nansum([NaN, NaN]) == 0.0` ([note the FutureWarning](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nansum.html)). For earlier versions, you'll have to check that case manually:

```
tmp = 3.25 * np.nansum(rs) +  .75 * np.nansum(rs * rs)
if not np.isnan(tmp):
  runningSum += tmp
```

Alternately, you could build up a list/array of `tmp` values and call `np.nansum` on that.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**:

All you need to change is this line in `testNotMask`:

```
runningSum += 3.25 * np.sum(rs) +  .75 * np.dot(rs, rs)
```

to this:

```
runningSum += 3.25 * np.nansum(rs) +  .75 * np.nansum(rs * rs)
```

All the other operations work fine with NaN values, so you can get all the speed of non-masked arrays while still getting the correct result.

Here's proof. The function `fastNotMask` is just `testNotMask` with the above change applied.

```
In [63]: genotypes = np.random.binomial(3, .333, size=(5000, 200)).astype(float)

In [64]: pValues = np.random.uniform(0,1,5000)

In [65]: %timeit testMask(pValues, genotypes)
1 loops, best of 3: 11.3 s per loop

In [66]: %timeit testNotMask(pValues, genotypes)
1 loops, best of 3: 3.53 s per loop

In [67]: %timeit fastNotMask(pValues, genotypes)
1 loops, best of 3: 3.96 s per loop

In [68]: randjs = np.random.randint(0,200, 10)

In [69]: randis = np.random.randint(0,5000,10)

In [70]: genotypes[randis,randjs] = None

In [71]: %timeit testMask(pValues, genotypes)
1 loops, best of 3: 33 s per loop

In [72]: %timeit testNotMask(pValues, genotypes)
1 loops, best of 3: 3.6 s per loop

In [73]: %timeit fastNotMask(pValues, genotypes)
1 loops, best of 3: 3.98 s per loop

In [74]: testMask(pValues, genotypes)
Out[74]: 0.47606794747438386

In [75]: testNotMask(pValues, genotypes)
Out[75]: nan

In [76]: fastNotMask(pValues, genotypes)
Out[76]: 0.47613597091679449
```

Note that there's a slight difference in precision between `testMask` and `fastNotMask`. I'm actually not sure where this is coming from, but I'm going to assume that it's not important.

Comment: Cool, Thank you! After hours of googling numpy.nansum() never came up. My search fu is weak. Cheers.

Comment: Actually after putting it to the test, I am still getting `nan`s as the result from `fastNotMask`. See above. Sorry If I am being stupid here.

Comment: Ah, that's what I get for using bleeding-edge numpy. I've updated my answer accordingly.